# Reading from Service Bus via Qpid JMS client fails

Tags: servicebus, qpid

I am trying to connect to Windows Service Bus from Qpid JMS client.
Authentication and handshake succeeded, but can not get anything from a topic or queue.

My code is based on tutorial provided [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj841073.aspx).

On reading attempt getting message from Service Bus:

> The server was unable to process the request; please retry the
>   operation. If the problem persists, please contact your Service Bus
>   administrator and provide the tracking
>   id..TrackingId:583da4f8d58d4fa59dc9521c6f799cb8_GWIN-AN5B307EEHM,TimeStamp:11.7.2014.
>   7:44:17

My question is where can I find this tracking id on the Service Bus and get some details about it?
Has anyone had similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue was worked through on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-5889.

Junica answered his own question in the end via this comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/QPID-5889?focusedCommentId=14064891&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14064891

Comment: Robbie, thanks for pointing on my answer. Planned to provide the same today.